# Java Passing variables around classes

Tags: java, class

I am new to java and am trying to pass variables like in the following example from one class to another, im wondering is this possible and how i would go about it if it is.

As this code does not work as it is not static.

Main Class

```
public class testAll
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        One one = new One();
        Two two = new Two();


    }
}
```

The first class:

```
public class One
{

    public int test = 4;

    public int getTest()
    {
        return this.test;

    }


}
```

The second class:

```
public class Two
{

    public void value()
    {
        System.out.print("Var is: " + One.getTest());

    }


}
```

Thanks,

Naz

Comment: What exact variable are you trying to pass??? To where are you trying to pass it??? What is the exact error you're getting???

Comment: this sounds like a really bad idea

Comment: @PhilippSander idea is common, question is not so clear.

Comment: @SeniorJD So is to be avoided or used?

Comment: it is commonly used of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets consider this, if you want to access a variable in Class A from Class B then Class A needs to know about Class B.

```
public class A {

    public A(B classB){
        this.classB = classB;
    }

    public void printValue(){
        System.out.println(this.classB.getTest());
    }
}
```

Now you will need to pass an instance of ClassB to ClassA in the constructor so that Class A has a reference to ClassB when it calls printValue();

```
ClassB b = new ClassB();
ClassA a = new ClassA(b);
b.getTest();
a.printValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an instance for class One first. Try this

```
public void value()
{
    One one_object = new One();
    System.out.print("Var is: " + one_object.getTest());

}
```

Comment: Would this be the same object or a new object so i couldn't access the data, from the one declared in main?

Comment: this one is different and local to this method only.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Two {

    private One one;
    public Two(One one) {
        this.one = one;
    }

    public void printValue() {
        System.out.print("Var is: " + one.getTest());
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        One one = new One();
        Two two = new Two(one);

        two.printValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be wary about calling a method that just outputs a string `getValue`. That sort of implies that it will be returning something.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way - pass a reference or pass a value:

```
public class One {
    private int value = 0;
    public One(final int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() { return value; }
}

public class Two {
    private One one = null;

    public Two(final int value) {
        this.one = new One(value);
    }

    public Two(final One one) {
        this.one = one;
    }

    public int getValue() { return one.getValue(); }
}
```

When passing a reference to a One instance, the value is read from One and will only change it the value held inside the One instance changes. When passing a primitive (int, boolean ...) the value is copied and "owned" by the Two instance. Read some more about the differences of references and values to grasp the idea. It's quite simple, once you get the idea.